# not-null property references a null or transient value: in.dao.Teacher.address

Tags: hibernate

When i run this application it is giving the exception like org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: in.dao.Teacher.address , can any one please help below is my code

## Teacher.java

package in.dao;

public class Teacher  implements java.io.Serializable {

```
 private Integer tid;
 private Address address;
 private String teachername;

public Teacher() {
}

public Teacher(Address address, String teachername) {
   this.address = address;
   this.teachername = teachername;
}

public Integer getTid() {
    return this.tid;
}

public void setTid(Integer tid) {
    this.tid = tid;
}
public Address getAddress() {
    return this.address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getTeachername() {
    return this.teachername;
}

public void setTeachername(String teachername) {
    this.teachername = teachername;
}
```

}

## Teacher.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="in.dao.Teacher" table="teacher" catalog="sample">
        <id name="tid" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="tid" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="address" class="in.dao.Address" fetch="select">
            <column name="locationid" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="teachername" type="string">
            <column name="teachername" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are saving the `Teacher` entity it probably references address entity which hasn't been saved yet.

You can fix it by first saving the address and the setting the saved Address instance to teacher before saving it, for example:

```
Address mergedAddress = session.merge(address);
teacher.setAddress(mergedAddress);
session.merge(teacher);
```

Or you can set Cascade to `MERGE` on your `Address` property so that Hibernate will merge the address first before merging the `Teacher` entity.